# ¿Como pasar parámetros al @can en la vista correctamente?

Tags: laravel

Quisiera mostrar u ocultar un boton si el usuario cumple o no con la politica de acceso con la funcion @can pero tengo problemas.

En este caso en el controlador tengo la autorizacion así:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
     {
// REVISO AUTORIZACION PARA ACTUALIZAR DATOS EDITADOS.
$datousuario =Modelo::findOrFail($id);
$this->authorize('update', $datousuario);
.
```

.
Donde $datousuario envia a la policita

```
{"id": 1,"idusuario": "2","grupoid": "1”, etc
```

La politica la tengo definida como:

```
public function update(User $user, Modelo $datousuario)
     // POLITICA PARA EDITAR EL REGISTRO EN EDICION
     {
        if($user->id == $datousuario->idusuario){
            return true;
        }else{
        // SI ES EL USUARIO PERTENECE AL GRUPO DEL REGISTRO PASA
                $idgrupos=User::findOrFail(Auth()->user()->id)
                            ->grupospertenece
                            ->pluck('id');
            foreach($idgrupos as $key=>$value){
                if($datousuario->grupoid==$value){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

¿Cómo define el can en la vista para pasarle los parámetros correctamente y que funcione correctamente mostrando si tiene permiso y ocultando si no lo tiene?

```
@can(????????????)
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar">editar dato</button>
 @endcan
```

Comment: Hola BetaM. En el fondo que tengo que poner en @can para que me muestre o no el botón si puede o no editar.

Answer (score 0):

Si revisamos la documentación de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-blade-templates) podemos observar que:

La directiva **`@can`** acepta 2 argumentos:

- La acción que *puede hacer*
- El objeto sobre el cual trabajará dicha acción

Entonces la sinxtasis regular que observamos es(sacado de la documentación):

```
@can('update', $post)
    <!-- The Current User Can Update The Post -->
@elsecan('create', App\Post::class)
    <!-- The Current User Can Create New Post -->
@endcan
```

Te recomiendo le des un vistazo mas a profundidad al enlace provisto.